# .on('click') works, .css('display','block') works, but not together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I'm having a strange problem. I've got this:

```
<div id="tstbtn" style="width:10px; height:10px; background-color:green;"></div>
<div id="dvDRKN">
    <div id="dvPopup">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDDL" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Test" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', function (event) {
            if (!$(event.target).closest('#dvPopup').length) {
                $('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });

        $('#tstbtn').on('click', function () {
            $('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #dvDRKN
    {
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        position: fixed;
        display:none;
    }
    #dvPopup
    {
        position: fixed;
        padding: 20px 15px;
        background-color: white;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
    }
</style>
```

It's supposed to show the `#dvDRKN` div when I click the `#tstbtn` div, but it doesn't.

I've tested the following:

```
$('#tstbtn').on('click', function () {
        alert('test');
    });
```

And that worked fine.
I've also tested to input `$('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'block');` directly in the console, and that also works. But when I put the two together, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you use `MasterPages`? If so your element's `ID` has been changed. Inspect the element and you'll see it.

Comment: This code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3nzxnb1g/

Comment: That's because `#tstbtn` is child of `#dvPopup` and click event bubbles... So if you click on `#tstbtn`, the click event bound to `document` level is fired too, and the condition is reached too, and so...

Comment: add `return false` after the `$('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'block');` ,

Comment: @MelanciaUK Nope. The elements IDs remain unchanged.

Comment: @Venky Wow, that was simple! If you make it into an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @wmash yeah, but I need the code that you have removed :P

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson ah fair enough then. It seems as yo have a working solution now anyway :)

Comment: EDIT: in my previous comment, i meant **isn't child** instead of ***is***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return false;` to prevent it from bubbling to parent event which toggles the state of the `div`, which you don't want to happen.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).closest('#dvPopup').length) {
                    $('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });

            $('#tstbtn').on('click', function () {
                $('#dvDRKN').css('display', 'block');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```